# Soft close hinge or mechanism for this storage bench

Tags: cabinets, hinges

It’s sort of a challenging door because it’s at a 0 degree angle with the surrounding surfaces when closed.
[image: closed]
[image: closed closeup]
[image: open]

Comment: You might get better answers over in woodworking.stackexchange.com. I would suggest asking how to get a soft closing action, rather than assuming that mechanism must be in the hinge itself.

Comment: The search term you’re looking for is ”soft down lid stay”.

Comment: Do you have an issue using soft close struts instead of hinges?  Or something like this? https://www.amazon.com/Bench-Hinge-Safety-Torsion-Support/dp/B088MJYC8G

Comment: @Huesmann no, but how will I install it in this case? The inner walls are not flush with the top of the lid. I’d need to add a piece of wood or something to fill that 2” gap.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate I had seen those, but none seem like they would work because the inner wall of the bench does not line up with the edge of the lid.

Comment: @keshlam ok, I’ll try. That’s why I said “or mechanism”.

Comment: You could add a metal L bracket that brings the mounting point of the lid stay into line with the edge of the lid.

Comment: @RobinDavis you would glue/screw a block to the side and/or top of the bench (screws long enough to penetrate partially through the sides and top, but not penetrate).  Edge of block would be flush with the inside edge of the bench seat.  You would then screw your strut to the block.